# R: How to filter matrix with predicate function?

Tags: r

as R newbie I want to filter a matrix with certain predicate functions. 
For example, I want to filter out all identical elements in a row.

So I happily code a function like this:

```
af <- function(a){
     n        <- nrow(a)
     m        <- ncol(a)
     a_Folger <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=m)

     for(i in 1:n){
        for(j in 2:m){
           if( a[i,j] == a[i,j-1]) { 
              a_Folger[i,j]   <- a[i,j] 
              a_Folger[i,j-1] <- a[i,j]
           }
     }  
 }
 a_Folger
```

}

This works so far, but it does not smell "R" code....

Is there a better "R" way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what your actual data looks like and what you want it to look like? As of right now, you just have a matrix of 0s and are overwriting things with 0s. It would be helpful to see the actual data and see what you mean by "filter out all identical elements in a row".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something that *smells like "R" code!!!*. Are you sure??? Ok,
here's it:

```
t(apply(a,1,function(x){ y<-rle(x); y[[2]][y[[1]]==1]<-0; rep(y[[2]],y[[1]]) }))
```

It produced identical result to your `af` function and is faster (but does not win points in readability :). However, you get to learn how to use: `sample`, `[[`, `rle`, `apply`, `rep`, `t` and `system.time`.

```
> set.seed(1)
> a<-matrix(sample(1:10,100,replace=T),1000,1000)
> system.time(res1<-af(a))
   user  system elapsed
  4.680   0.000   4.683
> system.time(res2<-t(apply(a,1,function(x){ y<-rle(x); y[[2]][y[[1]]==1]<-0; rep(y[[2]],y[[1]]) })))
   user  system elapsed
  0.188   0.036   1.118
> all.equal(res1,res2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.
this one-liner looks promising & is something I have to digest.
(btw. I said "smell" not "stink" :) )

Comment: @karltietze pls consider selecting this answer if you found it useful :)